# How to stream a video from board BeagleBone Black with VLC in a LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming, vlc, beagleboneblack

I have a camera connect to board BeagleBone Black(BBB) through usb cable, BBB run Linux 3.8.13-bone70 armv7l. I want to use camera to record video and stream this video to PC through LAN, but it is not work.
Please help find out what is wrong here.
This is what I did:

1. SSH to BBB from my PC
2. Open terminal

Type command below :

```
debian@beaglebone$ cvlc -vvv  v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30 --sout 10.92.200.76 --sout-rtp-caching --live-caching=130
```

This is the VLC log result:

```
VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower (revision 2.0.6-0-gbe9623c)
   [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.0.6 Twoflower
   [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2013 VLC authors and   VideoLAN
  [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: revision 2.0.6-0-gbe9623c
         [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--enable-  static' '--build=arm-linux-gnueabihf' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector   --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed' '--config-cache' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-silent-rules' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--prefix=/usr' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc-nox' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--with-binary-version=dmo3' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-bonjour' '--enable-caca' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dirac' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libproxy' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-mux_ogg' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-oss' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt4' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-sdl' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-smb' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-vcdx' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--disable-goom' '--disable-portaudio' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-sqlite' '--disable-telx' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-atmo' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv' '--enable-libva' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-pvr' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-omxil' 'build_alias=arm-linux-gnueabihf' 'CC=ccache cc' 'CXX=ccache g++'
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 413 modules
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/debian/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities NEONv1 FPU 
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: looking for memcpy module: 1 candidate
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: using memcpy module "memcpy"
    [0x182358] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
    [0x182358] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
    [0x182358] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
    [0x182358] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
    [0x182358] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
    [0x270b0] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 3 candidates
    [0x270b0] main demux debug: no access_demux module matching "file" could be loaded
    [0x270b0] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 11.316 ms - Total 11.316 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 11.316 ms)
    [0x182358] main input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
    [0xaada8] main access debug: looking for access module: 2 candidates
    [0xaada8] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
    [0xaada8] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
    [0xaada8] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 6.382 ms - Total 6.382 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 6.382 ms)
    [0xa9f40] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
    [0xa9f40] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
    [0xa9f40] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
    [0xa9f40] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 588 KiB/s
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 8.946 ms - Total 8.946 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 8.946 ms)
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 0 candidates
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matched "smooth"
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.826 ms - Total 2.826 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.826 ms)
    [0xa9f40] main stream warning: failed to insert stream filter smooth
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 3.374 ms - Total 3.374 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3.374 ms)
    [0x182358] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
    [0xab7b8] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 1 candidate
    [0xab7b8] playlist demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
    [0xab7b8] main demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
    [0xab7b8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.799 ms - Total 4.799 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.799 ms)
    [0xae518] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
    [0xae518] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/debian/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
    [0xae518] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
    [0xae518] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
    [0xae518] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
    [0xae518] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
    [0xae518] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 26.369 ms - Total 26.369 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 26.369 ms)
    [0x182358] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
    [0xa09a0] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module: 1 candidate
    [0xa09a0] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
    [0xa09a0] main xml reader debug: TIMER module_need() : 5.055 ms - Total 5.055 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 5.055 ms)
    [0xab7b8] playlist demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
    [0x182358] main input debug: EOF reached
    [0xab7b8] main demux debug: removing module "playlist"
    [0xa9970] main stream debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
    [0xaada8] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
    [0x182358] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'Media Library' : 85.019 ms - Total 85.019 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 85.019 ms)
    [0xa9f40] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
    [0xa9f40] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
    [0xa9f40] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.843 ms - Total 4.843 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.843 ms)
    [0x182358] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
    [0x182358] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
    [0x182358] main interface debug: no interface module matching "inhibit,none" could be loaded
    [0x182358] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 5.137 ms - Total 5.137 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 5.137 ms)
    [0x182358] main interface error: no suitable interface module
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: playlist threads correctly activated
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: adding item `v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30' ( v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30 )
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: no interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none" could be loaded
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 9.679 ms - Total 9.679 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 9.679 ms)
    [0xaada8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
    [0x138f0] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
    [0xaada8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: using interface module "dummy"
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.683 ms - Total 4.683 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.683 ms)
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: resyncing on v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30 is at 0
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
    [0xb52005f8] main input debug: Creating an input for 'v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30'
    [0xb5000948] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`standard{mux="",access="",dst="10.92.200.76"}'
    [0xb5000948] main stream output debug: stream=`standard'
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out warning: missing value for option mux
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out warning: missing value for option access
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-standard-dst to 10.92.200.76
    [0xb5000ad8] stream_out_standard stream out error: no access _and_ no muxer
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out debug: no sout stream module matching "standard" could be loaded
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out debug: TIMER module_need() : 6.319 ms - Total 6.319 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 6.319 ms)
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
    [0xb5000ad8] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
    [0xb5000948] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `standard{mux="",access="",dst="10.92.200.76"}'
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: finished input
    [0xb52005f8] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: dead input
    [0xb52005f8] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30' : 13.824 ms - Total 13.824 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 13.824 ms)
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: nothing to play
    ^C[0x138f0] main libvlc debug: deactivating the playlist
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: deactivating the playlist
    [0x182ac8] main playlist export debug: saving Media Library to file /home/debian/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
    [0x182ac8] main playlist export debug: looking for playlist export module: 1 candidate
    [0x182ac8] main playlist export debug: using playlist export module "export"
    [0x182ac8] main playlist export debug: TIMER module_need() : 10.621 ms - Total 10.621 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 10.621 ms)
    [0x182ac8] main playlist export debug: removing module "export"
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: playlist correctly deactivated
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: removing all services discovery tasks
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: removing all interfaces
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: exiting
    [0xaada8] main interface debug: removing module "dummy"
    [0xa9f40] main interface debug: removing module "hotkeys"
    [0x229e0] main playlist debug: destroying
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: TIMER ML Load : Total 100.323 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 100.323 ms)
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: TIMER Items array build : Total 7.035 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 7.035 ms)
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: TIMER ML Dump : Total 20.123 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 20.123 ms)
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: removing stats
    [0x138f0] main libvlc debug: removing module "memcpy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Before digging in, please note that I did NOT test these commands. I just used your given command and modified them with working sout chains I have been using on a unix environment (Mac OS).

VLC's log tells you that there is an error in your stream chain:

```
[0xb5000948] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `standard{mux="",access="",dst="10.92.200.76"}'
```

Try to play around and modify your stream out chain (--sout) in order to stream:

```
debian@beaglebone$ cvlc -vvv  v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30 --sout='#standard{access=udp, mux=ts,sap,name=yout-stream,dst=10.92.200.76, port=1234}' --sout-rtp-caching --live-caching=130
```

and to record:

```
debian@beaglebone$ cvlc -vvv  v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30 --sout='#transcode{venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30},vcodec=h264,vb=800}:std{mux=mp4,dst="/Path/to/your/file.mp4",access=file}' --sout-rtp-caching --live-caching=130
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.